# How to filter objects by scope spring boot jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have class Student:

```
@Entity
class Student(
  var name: String? = null,
  var status: Boolean? = null
)
```

I want write a method can filter Student active (status = true) and can use after call a other function. Ex in StudentService define a function get name:

```
fun getByName(name: String) : Student {
   return studentRepository.getByName(name)
}
```

I expected return a list student have name and active:

```
val listStudent = studentService.getByName("name_input").active()
```

Where method "active()" I can define?

Answer (score 0):

`studentService.getByName("name_input")` returns `List<Student>` which does not have such method (`active()`).

To filter records on database side you should define `StudentRepository#getByNameAndStatus(String name, boolean status)` returns `List<Student>`.

Otherwise Java streams can be used

```
val listStudent = studentService.getByName("name_input")
                      .stream()
                      .filter(s-> s.status().equals(true))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: My meaning is want filter "Student active" on database. Not want filter on controller.
Use stream filter can make reduce performance, bro? Tks

Comment: So `getByNameAndStatus(String name, boolean status)` repository method would be better option. Using second approach you have got all students by name from database. And only then you filter them using java streams. It increases the load on the database

Comment: Thank bro! It seems there are only 2 solutions.